# How to calculate pow(2,n) when n exceeds 64 in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, unsigned-integer

So, I am new to programming in c++ and i came across this question where i need to calculate **pow(2,n)/2** where n>64 ?

i tried using unsigned long long int but as the limit of the c++ is only 2^64. So is there any method to calculate this.

***Edit:***

```
 1 < n < 10^5
```

The result of the expression is used in further calculation

The question is asked on online platform.So, i cant use libraries like gmp to handle large numbers.

**Question**

You are given with an array **A** of size **N**. An element ***Ai*** is said to be charged if its value (***Ai***) is greater than or equal to ***Ki***. ***Ki*** is the total number of subsets of array **A** that consist of element ***Ai***.
Total charge value of the array is defined as summation of all charged elements present in the array **mod (10^9)+7**.
Your task is to output the total charge value of the given array.

Comment: How big can n be?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result, print it? I'm pretty sure a simple `std::cout << std::setprecision(1000) << std::pow(2.l,n) << '\n';` should work.

Comment: If you want exact arithmetic, you should use a bignum library like gmp.

Comment: n varies upto 100000 i.e (10^5)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Implementations vary, but I'm not sure even modern implementations can get a thousand digits correct. 15 digits is easy, 30 is a bit of work.

Comment: The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library  https://gmplib.org, however consider what you want this for. If you are doing hard core number theory, go for it. If you are using this integer to do other computations, rethink your solution.

Comment: if you can afford loosing precision you can use `long double`

Comment: You might need to implement your own ultra-wide-exponent floating point type to represent that. What on earth are you going to _use_ your `2^100000` for after you've computed it?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Even long double doesn't usually have room for exponents of more than 15 bits.

Comment: Surely there's more to this problem? For example, maybe the question asks for `pow(2, n) mod p` or something like that?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). If the question only asks you to print the result, you might be expected to implement your own big integer library or something similar. Since you mentioned that you need to use the results in further calculations, it is likely possible to manipulate your formulas to avoid computations with large numbers like this. So please post the full problem.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `pow(2,n)/2` is `pow(2,n-1)`.

Comment: if you can answer in binary the answer is easy : 0b1 << n-1, so you generate a string with n-1 zeros and a 1 in front

Comment: I'd just cheat and [not use C++](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM0/BVqGgKDOvREHDSCFOwRIINP//BwA).

Comment: @harold: Seems you guessed right. Yet another "do you know the rules of modular arithmetic?" questions, in particular `(a*b) mod p == (a mod p * b mod p) mod p`.

Comment: The question does not ask you to calculate powers of 2. Since you ran into a technical limitation, I would guess the question's intent is for you to figure out how to get that result without needing to calculate numbers larger than 2^64.

Comment: Is that an exact copy of the question? I ask because with the way it is written, _**Ki**_ is either 0 or 1, as there is exactly one set consisting of element **_Ai_**. So the value of _**Ki**_ depends only on whether or not that set is a subset of array **A**. (There are more sets that *contain* "element **_Ai_**", but only one that *consists* of it.) Presumably that set will be a subset, but the question neglects to specify what **_Ai_** is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An important detail here is that you're not being asked to compute 2<sup>n</sup> for gigantic n. Instead, you're being asked to compute 2<sup>n</sup> mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7 for large n, and that's a different question.

For example, let's suppose you want to compute 2<sup>70</sup> mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 1. Notice that 2<sup>70</sup> doesn't fit into a 64-bit machine word. However, 2<sup>70</sup> = 2<sup>30</sup> · 2<sup>35</sup>, and 2<sup>35</sup> does fit into a 64-bit machine word. Therefore, we could do this calculation to get 2<sup>70</sup> mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7:

> 2<sup>70</sup> (mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7)
>
> = 2<sup>35</sup> · 2<sup>35</sup> (mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7)
>
> = (2<sup>35</sup> mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7) · (2<sup>35</sup> mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7) mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7
>
> = (34359738368 mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7) · (34359738368 mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7) mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7
>
> = (359738130 · 359738130) mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7
>
> = 129411522175896900 mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7
>
> = 270016253

More generally, by using [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), you can compute 2<sup>n</sup> mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7 for any value of n in a way that nicely fits into a 64-bit integer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

The common approach in serious numerical work is to rewrite the formula's. You store `log(x)` instead of `x`, and later when you do need `x` it will typically be in a context where you didn't need all those digits anyway.

Comment: While I completely agree with you that in serious numerical work expressing things via logarithms is a great idea, this seems like it's in the context of a programming contest problem where exact values are needed. My suspicion is that they're looking for exponentiation by squaring with repeated mods.